# Sending data to an indirect child in React.js on a click event

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that has two major components (Landing and Skills):

```
App = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return (

          <div>
            <Landing />
            <Skills category={category}/>
          </div>

      );
    }
});
```

Within "Landing", I have a SocialMenu component, that has a list of items (the list of items is fed to SocialMenu like: `<SocialMenu items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us']} />`.  On click, the item that is clicked is highlighted.

```
SocialMenu = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { focused: 0 };
    },

    clicked: function(index){
        this.setState({focused: index});
    },

        var self = this;

        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="testblocks">{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){

                    var style = '';

                    if(self.state.focused == index){
                        style = 'focused';
                    }

                    return <li key={index} className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

                }) }

                </ul>


                <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p> 

            </div>
        );

    }
});
```

What I would like to have happen, is have the index data from SocialMenu, passed to the Skills component.

However, I am not sure how to do that, because SocialMenu is a child of Landing, and not of Skills.  (pretty much I would like to keep the list in landing, but have the output of the click of that list be put in Skills).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like Flux to have [communication betweeen components that don't have parent-child relationship](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html):

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

So, for your case, you need to have a event like SELECT_SOCIAL that will pass the index information and your Landing component will have a listener to receive the index information.

Comment: Where would I put that event?

Comment: I recommend to read a [tutorial about Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content). But, in resume: your SocialMenu component will call an Action that do a Dispatcher with the index information. The index information can be stored in a Store. The Store is responsible to emit a event with the index information for all components with listeners for this event.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this?  There's not an easier way to pass this data to "App" and then to Skills using a prop?

Comment: You will be in trouble if starts to do this... As your app grow up, you will need more and more to resolve the communication problem between your components. Everything passing for App? Is not a good idea, the React works better and simple if the information have a clear path to flow. Flux exists to simplify the communication and maintain the components **React**ive.

Comment: Would you give me an example of how I would implement this with code?  It would really be helpful.

Comment: This will help you: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/. You will need to study about Flux to implement more complex cases, but is not that difficult. Stackoverflow will be here to help you with the doubts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105524/discussion-between-user1072337-and-dherik).

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need Flux for this. You probably will at some point, but if this is all you need to do, why don't you move the state up to the `App` component, and send it Landing & Skills components as props. You would probably also need to pass the `clicked` handler as a prop to `SocialMenu`.

Comment: That is what I originally thought to do.  Given this, how do I move the state up to the App component?